# An entire function is a polynomial iff the Taylor expansion around $0$ converges uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analyticity

> Let $g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ an entire function. Prove that the Taylor expansion around $0$ converges uniformly in all $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $g$ is a polynomial.

**1/2 PROOF**
I think I have successfully proved the "if " part since if $g$ is a polynomial, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$
g(z)=a_mz^m+a_{m-1}z^{m-1}+ \cdots + a_1z+a_0. \ \ 
$$
The taylor expansion takes the form
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n z^n
$$
with $b_n=g^{(n)}(0)/n!$. Differentiation of $g$ gives that $b_n=a_n$ for $n=0,1,\cdots, m$ and $b_n=0$ if $n>m$. Then if $k\geq m$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$
$$
\left| \sum_{n=0}^{k} b_n z^n - g(z) \right| = 0
$$
so , indeed, $\sum_{n=0}^{k} b_n z^n$ converges to $g$ uniformly.

**PROBLEM** Now, to prove the converse, I guess I have to do it by contrapositive and use the fact that $g$ is an entire function. However, I am pretty lost, and I think I am missing something very obvious since I am supposed to answer this with only the first 3 chapters of the book "Conway: Functions of One Complex Variable I ". **Any help or Hints will be very appreciated.**

Comment: You proved "if", not "only if". For the only if direction, have you seen the result that if an entire function "grows like a polynomial", then it is a polynomial?

Comment: Here is a hint, Let $f_k(x)$ be $k$-th taylor series expansion. That is $f_k(x) = \sum_{i=0}^k b_ix^i$ where $g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} b_i x^i$. Assuming that $f_k(x)$ converges uniformly to $g(x)$ we can find $N$ where $m > N$ implies that $|f_m(x)-g(x)| < \epsilon$. What does that tell you about $|f_m(x)-f_{m+1}(x)|$?

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for the correction, I haven´t seen that result, I think it needs integration theory to prove it. Do you think there is a direct proof?

Comment: @BillTrok THANKS A LOT. Following your hint: First we see $| f_m(z)-f_{m+1}(z)|=|b_m|$ but by the triangle inequality $| f_m(z)-f_{m+1}(z)| \leq 2\varepsilon$, since $\varepsilon>0$ was chosen arbitrary we have that $b_m=0$ for all $m>N$, then $g$ is a polynomial with degree N, right ??

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín not sure if it is a typo but $|f_m(z)-f_{m+1}(z)| = |b_{m+1}z^{m+1}|$. Then you use the fact that $|b_{m+1}z^{m+1}| < 2\epsilon$ is true for all $z \in \mathbb{C}.$

Comment: @BillTrok that's what I ment, thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @BillTrok for the hint. Here is the answer:

$\boldsymbol{(\Longrightarrow)}$ If the Taylor expansion of $g$, around 0 converges uniformly in all $\mathbb{C}$ to $g$, put $T_k(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{k} b_n z^n$, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $N=N(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if  $k\geq N$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then
$$
|T_k(z)-g(z)|<\varepsilon
$$
So, if we take $k\geq N$
$$
|b_{k+1}z^{k+1}|=|T_{k+1}(z)-T_{k}(z)| \leq |T_{k+1}(z)-g(z)|+|T_k(z)-g(z)|< 2\varepsilon \ \ \forall \ z \in \mathbb{C}
$$
this gives that $|b_{k+1}z^{k+1}|$ is arbitrary small for larges $|z|$, then we must have $b_{k+1}=0$ for all $k \geq N$, which gives that $g$ is in fact a polynomial with degree $N$.

Comment: If you already know Liouville's theorem, you can get a different argument using that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes know it, however, I was not supposed to use it for this problem since It appears before Integration theory. Thank you for the hint anyway.