# Entire function either constant or has a zero

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose that a Taylor series of an entire function $f$ converges to $f$ uniformly in $\mathbb{C}$. How do I show that either $f$ is a non-zero constant or $f$ has a zero?

I was thinking about either: if f is everywhere nonzero then form $g = 1/f $ and then use $ |fg| = 1 $ to show that $ f $ is bounded, hence constant, or suppose that $ f $ is not constant, then show that $ f $ has a zero somehow. But I don't know how to do either. How do I prove this?

Comment: You might want to drop the condition that the Taylor series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$, I think this is only satisfied by Polynomials.

Comment: @0x539 You can't drop it:for example the exponential function doesn't have a zero.

Comment: @ploosu2 You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Taylor series of $f$ converges uniformly to $f$, [$f$ is a polynomial function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233846/an-entire-function-is-a-polynomial-iff-the-taylor-expansion-around-0-converges). Therefore, if $f$ is not constant, then it has at least a zero, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.