# $f$ is a polynomial if the Taylor series in 0 converges uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function. Prove that the Taylor expansion around $0$ converges uniformly in all $\mathbb{C}$ implies that $f$ is a polynomial.

I know this has been proved here ([An entire function is a polynomial iff the Taylor expansion around $0$ converges uniformly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233846/an-entire-function-is-a-polynomial-iff-the-taylor-expansion-around-0-converges)) but I want to know if the following proof would be valid. If the Taylor series is constant then $f$ is also constant so we will focus on non-constant series.

Since all the k-partial sums $S_k$ of the Taylor series are polynomials they have a pole at infinity. Since for sufficiently high $k$, the distance in the infinity norm between $f$ and $S_k$ is arbitrarily close, $f$ must have a pole at infinity. Since $f$ is entire and it has a pole at infinity It must be a polynomial (we studied that as a result in class).

Is this argument right?

Comment: The idea is correct, though in formalizing the sentence "the distance in the infinity norm between  and  is arbitrarily close,  must have a pole at infinity" will lead you to pretty much the same proof you linked.